# call function with char**

Tags: c#, unsafe

There is a dll, which contains the function.

```
extern "C" __ declspec (dllexport) int iRun (int argv, char ** argc)
```

In the project on C # I connect dll, and the actual question.
It is possible and how to initialize variable char **?

Comment: wait a minute... why is argv an int and argc a char**?

Comment: just a bad habit - argC as char

Comment: i see.  i think the usual is argc = argument count (int), argv = argument values (char**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DllImport("Your.dll")]
internal static extern Int32 iRun(Int32 argv, out IntPtr argc);

IntPtr argc;
Int32 result = iRun(argv, out argc);
String argcString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(argc);
```

Have a look at the [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) Method reference.